# Automatically merge meta-data resources from libraries

Tags: android, android-library

I'm the developer of a library that makes use of APP_RESTRICTIONS. Till now I had the following configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.content.APP_RESTRICTIONS"
        android:resource="@xml/library_restrictions" />
```

However, one of our customers now contacted us because his build was failing after adding our library. It turns out that he uses another library which also provides APP_RESTRICTIONS. I know that I can use

```
tools:node="replace"
```

or

```
tools:node="merge"
```

however this basically means that just one of the restriction configurations get active since it is an attribute on the meta-data. What I need is the content of the two resource files merged automatically to guarantee that the configuration field shows up in the MDM solution. Does anyone know a solution other than informing the developer in the readme that he has to manually merge the content of these two files?

Comment: you would need to merge on the @xml level, which is not possible on android. Also you cannot have two APP_RESTRICTIONS in the manifest. I don't think this use case can be covered.